# SQL select rows that dont have a join pair

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

How can i do something like an opposite of join? For example from those two tables select values from table **alice** that are not in table **bob**:

```
alice:
id|name
--+----
1 |one
2 |two
3 |three
6 |six
7 |seven

bob:
id|a_id
--+----
15|1
16|2
17|3
```

to get this:

```
result:
name
----
six 
seven
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first instinct is to use subquery, combined with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM alice 
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT a_id 
                    FROM bob);
```

However, [a little more efficient](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/) way is to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.name
  FROM alice a
       LEFT JOIN bob b
            ON a.id = b.a_id
 WHERE b.a_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Also note that the `not in` approach will produce unexpected results unless you ensure the subquery cannot return any null fields.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, you right, at first I added `a_id IS NOT NULL` condition to the subquery, but then realized, `a_id` must be a foreign key, therefore it can not be `NULL`

Comment: Er, what? A foreign key certainly can be null. Nor is the column referenced by a foreign key required to be non-null, btw, it can be a simple `unique` constraint and doesn't have to be a `primary key`.

Answer (score 8):

This is called an [anti-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29).

The general idea is to do a left, right, or full outer join, and filter to find only rows where the outer side is null.

For your example case, that'd be a left anti semi join:

```
select a.id, a.name
from alice a
left outer join bob b on (a.id = b.a_id)
where b.id is null;
```

but it's also possible to find mismatches on both sides with a full outer join:

```
select a.id, a.name
from alice a
full outer join bob b on (a.id = b.a_id)
where b.id is null
   or a.id is null;
```

For the left anti join approach, you can instead use `not exists`:

```
select a.id, a.name
from alice a
where not exists (select 1 from bob b where b.a_id = a.id);
```

though in practice PostgreSQL will transform this into join form anyway.

It's possible to use `not in` instead:

```
select a.id, a.name
from alice a
where a.id not in (select b.a_id from bob);
```

but:

- You have to make sure there can be no nulls in the subquery result, because `1 not in (2, null)` is `null` not `true`;
- It can be much less efficient

so in general using an anti-join or exists subquery is strongly preferred.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM alice WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT a_id FROM bob)
```

I hope "table a" is a made-up name and not the real name of your table.